# Chrome -webkit-transform: scale($val) does not anti-alias scaled image

Tags: google-chrome, css, css-transforms

For some reason, Chrome does not re-antialias images once they've been scaled up using a transform, whereas Safari seems to do so. The spec seems to think Safari is right, so I'm not sure what to do other than file a bug for Chrome.

Any suggestions?

[Sample Image](http://cl.ly/0u1l3w2x373k0v3B3n46)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using Snowstack, which first scales up the thumbnail and then updates it with a higher res version. Be patient, and you will notice it updates to the higher res version in Chrome too.

Comment: I am, in fact, using snowstack, but that was my first thought after reading through the code, and it's not the case here. Even after setting the zoom and thumb images to be the same it does not change anything. As far as I can tell Chrome is using the image that has first been downscaled as the source for upscaling and is losing fidelity in the process

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using? I'm using Chrome 15.0.864 here and it scales fine.